# Importing module in django installed with easy_install

Tags: django, easy-install

I just installed django-stdimage with easy_install on my server.

It told it me installed successfully at /home/myuser/lib/python2.4/django_stdimage-0.2.2-py2.4.egg

How do I import stdimage with django to start using it?

Comment: Have you followed the documentation? http://code.google.com/p/django-stdimage/#Usage

Comment: The docs don't say anything about using easy_install

Comment: I guess I just need to know how to import the module which is installed now at the given path

Comment: have you tried importing it like it says in the docs? Is there an error? If so, what is it? How is your project set up? Are you using virtualenv or is your application using the system wide python install? We can't guess how your server is set up. If you are NOT using something like virutalenv then django-stdimage should be on the python path and therefore accessible by just importing it as per the docs I linked to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Easy_install's .egg files are just .zip files. I unzipped the file where it was installed and then imported the module:

from stdimage import StdImageField